# Main difference between global and document colors in Sketch>

Tags: color

I would simply like to know the main difference between both type of colors in Sketch.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global colors is a custom palette you can use across all currently open sketch projects. If you have 3 sketch windows up with 3 different projects, you can use this palette across all of them.

The document-specific palette is just for the window/project you're currently viewing.